# django - subclassing a model just to add new methods

Tags: python, django

I need to subclass a model from a third-party app (`django-oscar`).

If i do this

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import Category

class NewCategory(Category):
    @property
    def product_count(self):
        return self.product_set.all().count()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'catalogue_category'
```

Django will think that it is a multi-table inheritance, and `NewCategory` is a child model for `Category`. This will result in errors such as

```
OperationalError at /api/categories/
no such column: catalogue_category.category_ptr_id
```

I can get away with this

```
def product_count(self):
    return self.product_set.all().count()

Category.product_count = product_count
```

but this doesn't seem nice, plus I am unable to add a `@property` decorator this way.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#proxy-models).

```
class NewCategory(Category):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    ...
```